# row number of First cell in a column with specific condition

Tags: excel

The cells in column A are Date type.

How can I get the row number corresponding to the first cell whose month is equal to a certain number?

Answer (score 1):

Try `MATCH()` function.

```
=MATCH(9,MONTH(A1:A12),0)
```

[image]

If you date stars from few row below then try

```
=MATCH(9,MONTH(A8:A19),0)+ROW($A$7)
```

[image]

Comment: If this formula uses as an array formula ({=MATCH(9,MONTH(A1:A12),0)}), it's true, I don't want an array formula.

Comment: My goal is , for example for first picture, write a code in VBA that compute a certain formula just for specific month and write that in column B.